# Почему управление input radio с помощью js не вызывает событие?

Tags: javascript

Следующий код ничего не выведет в консоль, но если переключать `input` вручную, то все срабатывает

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((item) => {
  item.onchange = function () {
    console.log(123);
  };
});

document.querySelectorAll("input")[1].checked = true;
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="myradios" value="1" chekced />
  <input type="radio" name="myradios" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="myradios" value="3" />
</form>
```

Comment: `chekced` что за слово модное такое?

Comment: А почему что-то должно выводиться в консоль, если события `change` не было? Вы просто изменили свойство элемента. [new Event()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)

Comment: когда Вы изменяете элемент с помощью .prop=.... change в данном случае не произойдёт. Можете например, с имитировать клик на кнопку. Так будет работать: `document.querySelectorAll("input")[1].click();`

Comment: @DmitriiSedov оставьте ваш рабочий ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам рабочий вариант на основе комментариев.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((item) => {
  item.onchange = function () {
    console.log(123);
  };
});

document.querySelectorAll("input")[1].click();
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="myradios" value="1" checked />
  <input type="radio" name="myradios" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="myradios" value="3" />
</form>
```